# What are three-point functions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, correlation-functions

I came across this term while I was trying to read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11107) related CFT correlators. Can some please take some time out to explain what does it mean in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [$n$-point correlation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(quantum_field_theory)) in quantum field theory is the (vacuum) expectation value of a product of $n$ field operators.